# How to get the value selected on a Spinbox with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Spinbox with the values (480, 1024, 2048, 5000, 10000) and a Button. Is there a way so I can get the value of selected in the Spinbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[get()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/spinbox.htm#Tkinter.Spinbox.get-method)

Remember to refer to the documentation for questions like these.